# Multicast File Transfers

Tags: linux, file-transfer, multicast

I'm looking for some multicast file transfer software. Do you have any suggestions? Must be "quickly implementable", i.e. no Tivoli or other stuff that requires a massive infrastructure. Must run on Linux. Note that I'm not looking for cloning software, I'm looking to move a bunch of large files around to a bunch of systems on the same LAN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We ended up fiddling with [uftpd](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net), and [mrsync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mrsync/), but ended up using mrsync. It basically used a combination of rsync over ssh to determine what needed to be transfered, and a multicast client and server to do the actual transfers. We were pretty happy with it, all things considered. We did have to do a bit of fiddling to make the firewalls allow through, but that wasn't too difficult, and once we got it done things worked well.

Probably the most impressive push we did was ~35 GB to about 170 systems in 12 minutes.

Comment: +1 for a great solution

Comment: +1, very good answer. I wish you described the advantage of mrsync over uftpd. Anyway, given that mrsync hasn't been updated since 2009, I doubt if the advantage still holds.

Comment: @SadeqDousti The advantages weren't so much about the speed difference, but more about usability, personal preferences, and our specific use case; which is why I didn't elaborate on them in the answer. You'll have to do your own evaluation to make a determination about which is better for your particular needs.

Answer (score 2):

uftp is working for me.  I ended up maxing the "robust" -s option to 50, and opening the server firewall to the ip's of the clients for the registration phase.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this may work for you...

bittorrent murder

http://github.com/lg/murder/blob/master/README.md

Comment: murder does not use multicast. It uses a distributed model.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in the Ubuntu package repositories gives me [Flamethrower](http://freshmeat.net/projects/flamethrower/).  It's developed as part of an image cloning solution, but supposedly works on its own too.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a tool called Udpcast: http://www.udpcast.linux.lu/

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHNJPL-GOO4) for a sample usage on Windows (I think the same holds for other platforms, such as Linux).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.